# Xcode 6 Open Image with a Button

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to open multiple images with buttons, but don't know what to write to do this. Essentially I have 5 buttons, and each button is supposed to open a new UIImageview with that specific picture in a new View Controller. I have the outlet of the UIImageview and know I have to have an action for the button, but don't know what to write to open the specific image with each button. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Inside your `prepareForSegue:` method, use something like:

```
newViewController.imageView.image = whateverImageYouWantToSee
```